# Why `button tag` won't display dialog for confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my code.
In spite of the fact that it has confirm, it won't show any dialog when it's clicked.
Why?

View

```
<%= button_tag( :name => 'destroy', :class => "btn btn-danger", :confirm => 'Are you sure?') do %>
Remove
<% end %>
```

Comment: make sure javascript is in the asset pipeline.... this has gotten me before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `:data => { :confirm => ... }`

HTH

Answer (score 3):

What version of rails are you using?

Deprecate `:confirm` in favor of `:data => { :confirm => 'Text' }` option
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fc092a9cba5fceec38358072e50e09250cf58840

```rb
# I am using 3.2.11 and this works 
<%= button_tag(:name => 'destroy', :class => "btn btn-danger", :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}) do %>
Remove
<% end %>

# this will output <button name="destroy" confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
# notice confirm is a tag attribute, which won't be picked up by javascript
<%= button_tag(:name => 'destroy', :class => "btn btn-danger", :confirm => 'Are you sure?') do %>
Remove
<% end %>
```

If you are not using firebug, I strongly recommend you use it.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Always check the output HTML before going deep in ruby.